# Assign SwiftyJSON object to a String Array

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

Im working on a project in swift 3 and to call web services I use AlamoreFire and SwiftyJASON (pods). The Format as Bellow

```
    APIManager.apiGet(serviceName:appURLs.mainBaseURL+appURLs.testingPureLight, parameters: params) { (json:JSON?, error:NSError?) in
            if error != nil{

                print("error:",error as Any)

            }

            print(json!)
}
```

Therefore, I'm getting a Json response with type of JSON, thus,I get the following structure as my response.

```
 { 
  "media": [ {
    "key" : "value" 
    "Objectarray"[
     { "Object1":"somevalue" 
          "key2":"somevalue"
          "key3":"somevalue"
     } 

     {"Object2":"somevalue"
         "key2":"somevalue"
         "key3":"somevalue"
     } 

     { "Object3":"somevalue" 
          "key2":"somevalue"
          "key3":"somevalue"
     }

    ] 
  } ]
 }
```

My requirement is to catch this "Objectarray" and assign it to a string array so I could use it to populate in my UITableVIew. How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Is `Objectarray` contains key like `Object1`, `Object2`, `Object3`... or you have written like that.

Comment: Object array have Dictionary elements called Object1, Object2, Object3, and inside that only u get key value pairs. For instance inside Object1 may contains a pair and it could be like->  Object1{"name" : "john"}

Comment: What I'm asking is `Object1`,  `Object2`,  `Object3`... are actual keys?

Comment: yes they are keys but inside separate dictionaries, Ill update the code to make it more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your `Objectarray` this way.

```
var objects = [String]() 
if let jsonResponse = json,
   let objectArray = jsonResponse["media"][0]["Objectarray"].arrayValue {

    for object in objectArray {
        let object1 = object["Object1"].stringValue
        objects.append(object1)
    }
}
```

Comment: no sir as i have mentioned what i wants to know is how could i assign it to a string array and use it in my cellForRow method. With what u have written above, the type of object array is JSON. Not String

Comment: some bracket is missing i guess.Something wrong its not working. so many errors but got the basic idea though

Comment: @danutha Then you need to Proper your code and check where the bracket missing because in my answer there is no missing bracket, all the opening brackets have there closing bracket.